# How to authenticate Google Drive in asp.net without copy/pasting auth tokens

Tags: asp.net, authentication, google-drive-api

I am developing Web Application to Upload a file on Google Drive in ASP.NET using C#.

While running the Application I want to upload file automatically to Google Drive with automatic authentication technique.
Following is the class file used to upload file but unable to authenticate to Google API.There is something Wrong with GetAuthorization(). Please help me for that...

> ```
>    namespace Cloud
>      {
>       class Code
>     {
>     private static readonly string CLIENT_ID = "303453771054-   4ftp53uun2o6jeiii85i22muc4fio76f.apps.googleusercontent.com";
>     private static readonly string CLIENT_SECRET = "wMc6mptgMTOL1ncGSJX-qoPS";
>     private static readonly string APIKEY = "AIzaSyAVyZF8OVl4Vvrbu9pWUQCzx35afdpYJR0";
>     private static readonly string REDIRECTURI = "http://localhost:49632/CloudCode.aspx";
>     private static readonly string[] SCOPES = new[] { DriveService.Scopes.Drive.GetStringValue()           };
>    public void Main(string Filename)
>     {
>         var provider = new WebServerClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);
>         provider.ClientIdentifier = CLIENT_ID;
>         provider.ClientSecret = CLIENT_SECRET;
>         provider.RequestUserAuthorization();
>         provider.ProcessUserAuthorization(null);            
>         var authenticator = new OAuth2Authenticator<WebServerClient>(provider, GetAuthorization);
>         File body = new File();
>         body.Title = "My document";
>         body.Description = "A test document";
>         body.MimeType = "text/plain";
>         body.OriginalFilename = Filename;
>         byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(body.OriginalFilename.ToString());
>         System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);
>         DriveService service = new DriveService();
>         FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = service.Files.Insert(body, stream, "text/plain");
>         request.Upload();
>         File file = request.ResponseBody;           
>     }
>      private IAuthorizationState GetAuthorization(WebServerClient arg)
>     {           
>          IAuthorizationState   state = arg.ProcessUserAuthorization(new HttpRequestInfo(HttpContext.Current.Request));
>         IAuthorizationState AuthorizationState=new AuthorizationState(SCOPES);
>         AuthorizationState.Callback = new Uri(REDIRECTURI);
>         return AuthorizationState;
>     }
> ```

Comment: I don't think you can upload a file to somebody's google drive account without authentication.

Comment: Sorry actually I am developing Web Application to allow  clients to upload file on my Google drive with automatic authentication.

Comment: If you want to use your own account to store files, probably this will help https://developers.google.com/drive/service-accounts

Comment: @Andrey M. I followed all those steps but still it raises an unhandled exception as :- **Method not found: 'Google.Apis.Discovery.IParameter Google.Apis.Util.Utilities.CreateRuntimeParameter(System.String, Boolean, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.String>)'.** Please help me...

Comment: Could you post more code? I have tried to upload a file and I did not get the exception. Here is my controller code https://gist.github.com/andreymir/6371343

Comment: @ Andrey M. I have posted the code above. I saw your controller code I  didn't get it. When I execute my code there error is displayed in  Browser as :- **Error: invalid_request** & Request Details provided to the browser are 
response_type=code
redirect_uri=http://localhost:49632/CloudCode.aspx
client_id=303453771054-4ftp53uun2o6jeiii85i22muc4fio76f.apps.googleusercontent.com  Please help me...